# Daisy Chained NPM Package Functions with Meteor.wrapAsync()

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, meteor, npm

I am trying to use a Node package within my meteor app. Natively in node I'd need to daisy chain the calls together like so:

```
return client.auth(req.session.token, req.session.sec).user("_SELF_").find(function(err, body, headers) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (body) {
      console.dir(body);
    }
    if (body) {
      return res.send(body.results[0]);
    }
  });
```

I've tried several things without success. Such as:

```
  var authSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(client.auth, client);
  return authSync(req.session.token, req.session.sec).user("_SELF_").find(function(err, body, headers) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
        if (body) {
          console.dir(body);
        }
        if (body) {
          return res.send(body.results[0]);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that only the `find()` method is async.

Therefore, `client.auth(req.session.token, req.session.sec).user("_SELF_")` will return some object with a `find()` method and this is what you really need to wrap.

```
var user = client.auth(req.session.token, req.session.sec).user("_SELF_");
var findAsync = Meteor.wrapAsync(user.find, user);
try {
  var body = findAsync();
  return res.send(body.results[0]);
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

It will return whatever `result.send(...)` returns.

The callback does not comply with the standard error-first callback signature (`function(error, result){}`), but it should still work, although I don't think that there is any way of retrieving the third parameter (`headers`).

If you are doing this inside a method, using a directly Future may be more appropriate.